# Multiplying Columns in Active Record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Have the following sql query, how would I translate the multiplication of two columns in Active Record?

```
SELECT plan_name, plan_price, count(plan_id), plan_price*count(plan_id) AS totalrevenue
FROM leads
INNER JOIN plans p ON leads.plan_id = p.id
WHERE lead_status_id = 5
GROUP BY plan_name, plan_price;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd try something like this.

```
leads = Lead.joins(:plans).
    where(lead_status_id: 5).
    group(:plan_name, :plan_price).
    select('plan_name, plan_price, count(plan_id), plan_price * count(plan_id) AS totalrevenue')

leads.each { |lead| puts lead.totalrevenue }
```

Note:

1. I don't know if it's `joins(:plan)` or `joins(:plans)`, it depends on your associations
2. If you need to call even the `plan_id` count I'd give a name even to that field
3. A field like `totalrevenue` is not displaied if you print the entire object, because it's not part of it, it's a virtual attribute